# Summation in closed form

Tags: summation, summation-method, kronecker-delta

I have the following summation:
\begin{equation}
f(k_1,k_2) = \sum_{l_1 = 0}^{k_1}\sum_{l_2 = 0}^{k_2} {\rho}^{l_1+l_2}\delta[k_1-k_2+l_2-l_1]
\end{equation}

where $\rho$ is a constant and $\delta$ is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). I want to find a closed form of this summation but having difficulties. Can you help me out to simplify the equation?

Comment: Kronecker's delta need two indices

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes I edited the question. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are variables.

Comment: Even now it doesn't make sense for me

Comment: A. J. Pan-Collantes didn't say $f$ needs two indices. They said $\delta$ needs two indices. The Kronecker delta is $1$ if its **two** inputs are the same, and is $0$ otherwise. You don't have two inputs to $\delta$, only one. Until you fix that, your question does not make sense and we cannot be sure what you really mean.

Comment: @lordvoldemort Is $\delta_{l_1,l_2}$ meant?

Comment: It could be a binomial theorem alternative?